# Zero-truncated negative binomial model in glmmTMB predictions

Tags: r, mixed-model, predictive-models, negative-binomial-distribution, glmmtmb

I have a dataset of counts of a vocalisation per hour. I am interested in fitting a model to see if the count of the vocalisations of a given category per hour is effected by noise. My response variable is vocalisation count and my predictor variables are Year (factor) and Noise (continuous). My random variable is the vocalisation category.

Counts are always >0 so I tried fitting a truncated poisson model but the model fit was poor (as determined by the DHARMa package) so I fit a truncated negative binomial which improves model fit. However, when I plot model predictions, the predicted counts are extremely small which doesn't make sense, given the minimum value in my response variable is 1.

Is this a problem with the ggpredict() function for models fit this way, or rather an issue with suitability of this model? Can anybody suggest a better model for this data?

A sample of my data that recreates the problem:

```
data <- structure(list(count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 21, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 
                                 2, 5, 2, 9, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
                                 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 12, 1, 1, 2, 1, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 
                                 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 8, 1, 1, 4, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L), .Label = c("2018", "2020"), class = "factor"), Noise = c(100.14816798109, 
                                                                                                                                  100.377104664689, 100.207329855322, 100.11241514045, 100.112717643028, 
                                                                                                                                  100.118437867929, 100.119542289451, 79.0761848334307, 102.039606409679, 
                                                                                                                                  100.112717643028, 95.2502441040289, 89.7516652811825, 88.2557157523884, 
                                                                                                                                  84.5670636708441, 84.9808360182281, 83.6350824002886, 100.11812407517, 
                                                                                                                                  100.181121754611, 100.186963879715, 100.112765144526, 100.115410572088, 
                                                                                                                                  100.118125952527, 100.910393178498, 100.377104664689, 100.308102087632, 
                                                                                                                                  100.241719139521, 101.291677480681, 100.119658124984, 100.107649510248, 
                                                                                                                                  100.151948591508, 100.21998340289, 100.20853069868, 100.114002381474, 
                                                                                                                                  100.119542289451, 100.168216083649, 77.6787976861261, 87.5293915298482, 
                                                                                                                                  85.1630753294396, 77.495811461613, 87.5607861337519, 88.3763652204667, 
                                                                                                                                  88.1665934234852, 89.9371317239202, 90.2907087376785, 88.952935505725, 
                                                                                                                                  89.7516652811825, 94.9968561826337, 84.679232276739, 84.5670636708441, 
                                                                                                                                  100.11812407517, 100.156936897038, 100.14816798109, 100.181121754611, 
                                                                                                                                  100.82220297026, 106.705003189727, 100.186963879715, 100.105376972717, 
                                                                                                                                  100.112765144526, 100.382899894133, 100.118125952527, 100.113098085388, 
                                                                                                                                  100.910393178498, 100.377104664689, 100.308102087632, 100.152292684022, 
                                                                                                                                  100.12075895405, 100.11473827418, 101.291677480681, 100.173559873355, 
                                                                                                                                  100.21998340289, 100.129446657206, 100.108551242703, 100.110635777745, 
                                                                                                                                  100.10943118329, 100.20853069868, 100.378012393608, 100.116924546606, 
                                                                                                                                  100.114002381474, 100.119542289451, 77.6787976861261, 74.9390116331616, 
                                                                                                                                  82.5999760158118, 80.9621696280011, 74.9615420206442, 83.9577407604614, 
                                                                                                                                  88.1561301906344, 84.7444294815382, 72.9307598534381, 75.2065487926489, 
                                                                                                                                  79.0299184413746, 87.5293915298482, 85.1809077867005, 84.7470968091893, 
                                                                                                                                  84.4430934188494, 87.5607861337519, 85.4130212934696, 88.3938483677018, 
                                                                                                                                  89.9371317239202, 88.952935505725, 86.8513185995587, 76.6291888075213, 
                                                                                                                                  79.6072335769646, 79.9351797132717, 88.0068437203196, 87.7824188709195, 
                                                                                                                                  88.2557157523884, 86.6066778250837, 82.3877216580678, 90.6528608123552, 
                                                                                                                                  84.679232276739, 77.4738015422633, 84.5670636708441, 91.4926287832699, 
                                                                                                                                  91.7965671147401, 89.613165802416, 86.2546932166033, 84.0775662502714, 
                                                                                                                                  83.6350824002886, 100.14816798109, 100.141425299166), Category = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 120L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
    library(ggeffects)
    library(glmmTMB)
    library(DHARMa)
    mod<-glmmTMB(count ~ Year + Noise + (1|Category), family=truncated_nbinom2(link = "log"), data=data)
    simulationOutput<-simulateResiduals(fittedModel = mod, plot=T) 
    testDispersion(mod) #Non significant
    testOutliers(simulationOutput, type=c("bootstrap")) #Non significant
    summary(mod)
    preds<-ggpredict(mod, terms=c("Noise"))
    plot(preds)
```

[image]

Comment: The code to generate the dataset doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated it so should work now hopefully

Answer (score 1):

`ggpredict()` is more or less a wrapper around `predict(type = "response")`, and results for a similar example (with counts > 0) are consistent:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(ggeffects)

Salamanders$count2 <- Salamanders$count + 1
table(Salamanders$count2)
#> 
#>   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  37 
#> 387  79  61  30  29  17  10  12   6   3   2   3   1   2   1   1

m <- glmmTMB(count2 ~ spp + mined + (1 | site),
             family = truncated_nbinom2("log"),
             data = Salamanders)

ggpredict(m, "spp")
#> # Predicted counts of count2
#> 
#> spp   | Predicted |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#> GP    |      0.19 | [0.10, 0.34]
#> PR    |      0.05 | [0.02, 0.10]
#> DM    |      0.27 | [0.15, 0.47]
#> EC-A  |      0.09 | [0.05, 0.17]
#> EC-L  |      0.33 | [0.19, 0.58]
#> DES-L |      0.41 | [0.24, 0.71]
#> DF    |      0.25 | [0.14, 0.44]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * mined = yes
#> *  site = NA (population-level)

nd <- data.frame(spp = levels(Salamanders$spp),
                 mined = "yes",
                 site = NA,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
predict(m, newdata = nd, type = "response")
#> [1] 0.18563550 0.04939203 0.26713234 0.09098044 0.32819179 0.40882536 0.25144930
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting it's still predicting counts <1 in this case as well, if I'm interpreting correctly?