# Back Transformed Truncated Negative Binomial Model Results Less Than One

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, back-transformation, truncated-distributions

I'm using a truncated negative binomial model to describe my count data where all values are >=1. I have attempted to back-transform my model results using emmeans. However, all of my back transformed estimates are <1 which doesn't make sense to me when all of my data are >=1. The raw means are all ~1.4-1.8. Is this simply a function of the back-transformation of log scaled results not being identical to the log of the raw means or am I missing something?

I saw a similar question here [Zero-truncated negative binomial model in glmmTMB predictions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582070/zero-truncated-negative-binomial-model-in-glmmtmb-predictions) but no answer was provided to the question concerning the back-transformed values being <1.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: Show what model you fitted, how you used emmeans, and some output. Otherwise we have to guess what you did, and we'll probably guess wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.